# Diffusion process in p-n junction

Tags: semiconductors

While studying about Semiconductors I couldn't get why "Negative charge stop electrons from further diffusion and Positive charge stop holes from further diffusion" as stated in (p.6) of the [semiconductors](http://1drv.ms/11zNA6J).

Also which carriers(minority or majority) take part in the diffusion process?Do both of them take part in the diffusion process?Could anyone help me.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is pulled from the Wiki : [Depletion Region in a PN Junction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depletion_region#Formation_of_depletion_region_in_a_p.E2.80.93n_junction)

> diffused electrons come into contact with holes on the P-side and are eliminated by recombination. Likewise for the diffused holes on the N-side. The net result is the diffused electrons and holes are gone, leaving behind the charged ions adjacent to the interface in a region with no mobile carriers (called the depletion region). The uncompensated ions are positive on the N side and negative on the P side. This creates an electric field that provides a force opposing the continued exchange of charge carriers. When the electric field is sufficient to arrest further transfer of holes and electrons, the depletion region has reached its equilibrium dimensions.

Both carriers take part in the diffusion process. The diffusion is halted by the electric potential formed at the junction as a result of the process.

Answer (score 0):

In n-type semiconductor, electrons are minority carriers because they far outnumber the holes, so holes are minority carrier. When the electrons enter p-type semiconductor, it becomes minority carriers. The situation is opposite in p-type semiconductor.

> In the diffusion process, particles flow from a region of high
>   concentration to a region of lower concentration. This is a
>   statistical phenomenon related to kinetic theory. To explain, the
>   electrons and holes in a semiconductor are in continuous motion, with
>   an average speed determined by the temperature, and with the
>   directions randomized by interactions with the lattice atoms.
>   Statistically, we can assume that, at any particular instant,
>   approximately half of the particles in the high-concentration region
>   are moving away from that region toward the lower-concentration
>   region. We can also assume that, at the same time, approximately half
>   of the particles in the lower concentration region are moving toward
>   the high-concentration region. **However, by definition, there are fewer
>   particles in the lower-concentration region than there are in the
>   high-concentration region. Therefore, the net result is a flow of
>   particles away from the high-concentration region and toward the
>   lower-concentration region. This is the basic diffusion process.**

So, both minority and majority carriers will diffusion, but the net result is a high-concentration to lower-concentration diffusion.

The flow of holes from the p-region uncovers negatively charged acceptor ions, and the flow of electrons from the n-region uncovers positively charged donor ions. This action creates a charge separation (in your Figure 3), which sets up an electric field oriented in the direction from the positive charge to the negative charge. The direction of the induced electric field will cause the resulting force to repel the diffusion of holes from the p-region and the diffusion of electrons from the n-region.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But could you tell how the induced electric field will cause the resulting force to repel the diffusion of both carriers?Also do you mean the 'induced electric field' as the voltage applied or does it mean the voltage formed by diffusion.

Comment: In your figure 3, the middle part, the diffusion results a depletion region, there is a filed from right to left (like a plate capacitor), just this filed. You know this filed will prevent the majority carriers (positive charge) in p region diffusion across it.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of space charge is involved here.Because of diffusion of holes from P region to N region and diffusion of electrons from N region to P region a net negative charged region is formed at th P region and a Net positively charged region is formed at the N region.these to regions act as a two plates of a capacitor with a net charge between the plates.This charge is called the Space charge The capacitance prevents the flow of charges in any direction.Because capacitor is a sync for charges .The concept of diffusion capacitance is important in understanding diode operations

Answer (score 0):

Here are some quick answers:
Internal electric field within the pn -junction. and both holes and electrons are particles that can move around within the material.

Well as a 3rd year physics student I did a report on semiconductors. Here is some more theory for you to make sense of this which I wrote out of my own understanding. Here you go ;)

"It is important to remember that the material is neutral! When pn-junctions are formed, excess electrons from the n-side move over to the p-side by diffusion and the same process may apply to the holes. This is known as the diffusion current. The diffusion process leaves a depletion region near the such that as the charges build up, a net positive charge and net negative charge are created at the p- and the  n-side respectively. Now an electric field is created within in the depletion region and creates a drift current that opposes the diffusion current. Eventually the drift current will equal the diffusion current and an equilibrium will be established where no more charge carriers can move across."

Answer (score 0):

I have recently managed to get working electron diffusion model of p-n junction: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.12557

It is crucial not to use standard diffusion (GRW, leading to nearly uniform density), but maximizing entropy one (MERW): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_entropy_random_walk .

MERW has stationary density exactly as quantum mechanics - with [Anderson localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson_localization): electrons localize in p, unless exceeding some threshold voltage to overcome it for conductance - see example simulation below:

[image]

Comment: How does any of this help the OP?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, OP asks about "diffusion process in p-n junction", here is such actual working statistical mechanics model - of electron diffusion stimulated by external voltage, much easier in forward bias.